# iOS - accessing a property in an unknown view controller

Tags: ios, class, casting

In the appDelegate, I want to do something in case the visible view controller is kind of class `MyViewController`. Then I want to check the property `myVar` that is defined in the `MyViewController` class. This is my code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self visibleViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    if (vc.myVar == "foo") {
         // do something
    }
}
```

I have an error saying: `Property myVar not found on object type of 'UIViewController *'`
How do I tell the code that I'm sure now that vc is a type of `MyViewController` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sure that vc is an MyViewController object, but in the next line vc is still considered as a UIViewController. You can create a MyViewController pointer or cast it automatically :

```
UIViewController *vc = [self visibleViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {

    MyViewController * myViewControllerVc = (MyViewController *)vc;

    if (myViewControllerVc.myVar == "foo") {
         // do something
    }
}
```

or

```
UIViewController *vc = [self visibleViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    if (((MyViewController *)vc).myVar == "foo") {
         // do something
    }
}
```

I tend to use the first solution when i will use more than once the custom class properties, otherwise i use the second one.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is casting

```
UIViewController *vc = [self visibleViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    if ([(MyViewController *)vc myVar] == "foo") {
         // do something
    }
}
```